# how do i make colonies in europa universalis 4 help me in my wars

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I have been playing Europa Universalis 4 for a while, and i was wondering if there were any mods, or the like that makes my colonies help me in my wars. For example, say i'm a country with lots of colonies, and im at war against a country that has no colonies. in this case my own colonies don't do anyhting to help me in my war, so it would be awesome if there were any mods or game file tweaking i could do that changes it.

Comment: Sometimes your colonies may take part in your war on the european continent, depending on if they have the resources (troops, boats, money). What you can try is send some transports overseas with one of your troops, and select the "Attach to this army" option (or something akin to that), and see if they cooperate.

Answer (score 1):

Your colony is an ally to you. They will reach you at war if they are able to and willing, like any other allies.

**They are likely to come if...**

- They have a path to reach your territories or the enemy's one
- They have boats and an army
- They are loyal to you. If they are upset, they probably never come
- Have gold (at least, no debts)

A good trick, like Laf said in comment, is to bring a ship with a small army stack. Select the "Attach to this unit" box and see if they come.